# How to apply a filter in a LINQ to SQL expression only if results exist when the filter is applied?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, expression-trees

I have a function I'd like to transform into a LINQ to SQL expression, but I can't figure out how. This function is called from within a LINQ query, once for each row in the result set. The productAreaId being passed in may or may not refer to valid data, so I have to check, and then only filter by productAreaId if any rows exist after applying the filter:

```
//Forgive the contrived example...
public static IQueryable<Order> GetOrders(int orderNumber, int? productAreaId, 
    OSDataContext db)
{
    var orders = db.Orders.Where(o => o.OrderNumber == orderNumber &&
        o.Group.GroupTypeId != (int)GroupTypeId.INTERNAL &&
        !o.Deleted);

    if (productAreaId != null)
    {
        var orders2 = orders.Where(o => o.ProductAreaId == productAreaId);
        if (orders2.Any()) return orders2;
    }
    return orders;
}
```

I don't want to do it like this. I need a function that returns an expression without arbitrary code, so it will be composable. The above function is only displayed because it's the only way I know how to encapsulate this in a function.

I'd like to do something like this, with the contrived "ApplyFilterIfAnyResultExists" replaced with something that actually works:

```
public static Expression<Func<Order,bool>> 
    GetOrdersExpr(int orderNumber, int? productAreaId)
{
    return o => o.OrderNumber == orderNumber && 
        o.Group.GroupTypeId != (int)GroupTypeId.INTERNAL &&
        !o.Deleted && (productAreaId == null || 

            //Making up a fictional function. Is there a real way to do this?
            o.ApplyFilterIfAnyResultExists(row => 
                row.ProductAreaId == productAreaId)
        );
}
```

Is there any way to apply that kind of filter within a LINQ to SQL expression? If not, any suggestions?

Thank you!
Roy

**EDIT:**
This is the main query as I'd like it to look:

```
var customerData = 
    from c in db.Customers
    select new 
    {
        id = c.Id,
        name = c.Name,

        lastOrder =
            db.Orders
            .Where(GetOrdersExpr(c.LastOrderNumber, 
                c.PreferredProductAreaId))
            .FirstOrDefault(),

        allOrders = c.OrderForms
            .Select(form => 
                db.Orders
                .Where(GetOrdersExpr(form.OrderNumber,
                    c.PreferredProductAreaId))
                .FirstOrDefault()
            )
            .Where(o => o != null)

        //How lastOrder used to be queried
        //lastOrder =
        //    GetOrders(c.LastOrderNumber, c.PreferredProductAreaId, db)
        //    .FirstOrDefault()
    };
```

It's also worth noting that Orders and Customers are in two different databases on the database server, but they're both referenced from the same DataContext here.

Comment: So you're saying that even if a product area is specified, you don't want to apply the filter if there are no matching orders once the filter is applied?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
var customerData = 
    from c in db.Customers
    let orders = db.Orders.Where(o => o.OrderNumber == c.orderNumber &&
        o.Group.GroupTypeId != (int)GroupTypeId.INTERNAL &&
        !o.Deleted)
    let orders2 = orders.Where(o => o.ProductAreaId == c.productAreaId)
    select new 
    {
        id = c.Id,
        name = c.Name,
        lastOrder = c.productAreaId != null && orders2.Any() ?
            orders2.FirstOrDefault() :
            orders.FirstOrDefault() 
    };
```

Comment: Thanks, this pointed me in the right direction. The let keyword is great!

Answer (score 1):

For your original method, this might work better:

```
public static IQueryable<Order> GetOrders(int orderNumber, int? productAreaId, 
    OSDataContext db)
{
    var orders = db.Orders.Where(o => o.OrderNumber == orderNumber &&
        o.Group.GroupTypeId != (int)GroupTypeId.INTERNAL &&
        !o.Deleted);
    if(productAreaId != null)
    {
        orders = orders.Where(
            o => !orders.Any(o2 => o2.ProductAreaId == productAreaId) ||
                    o.ProductAreaId == productAreaId);
    }
    return orders;
}
```

This makes it so you're only doing a single database roundtrip. If the product area ID is provided, you will return orders where either:

- none of the orders in the original query have that area ID, or
- this order does have that area ID

It does make the query more complex, so I'd test it a bit to see if it really gives you any performance gains.

This won't translate very well to the function that you're suggesting, but if you share more information about how this code is getting called, I could probably give you some advice on how to avoid calling this function 20+ times.

**Edit**

Something like this should work:

```
var customerData = 
    from c in db.Customers
    let productAreaId = c.PreferredProductAreaId
    let orders = 
        db.Orders
        .Where(o => o.OrderNumber == c.LastOrderNumber &&
            o.Group.GroupTypeId != (int)GroupTypeId.INTERNAL &&
            !o.Deleted)
        .OrderBy(o => o.Date)
    let lastOrderInProductArea = productAreaId != null
        ? orders.FirstOrDefault(o => o.ProductAreaId == productAreaId)
        : null
    select new 
    {
        id = c.Id,
        name = c.Name,
        lastOrder = lastOrderInProductArea != null
            ? lastOrderInProductArea
            : orders.FirstOrDefault()
    };
```

Comment: I'm really trying to move away from this approach. The function needs to return an Expression<Func<Order,bool>>, not an IQueryable. If I return an IQueryable, the function is not composable into a larger query.

Comment: @Roy Tinker: Please provide more information on how you're calling this function, so I can get an idea of what options you might have.

Comment: By the way, nice suggestion for the original method... just not what I'm looking for at the moment :-|

Answer (score 0):

```
public static IQueryable<Order> GetOrders(int orderNumber, int? productAreaId, OSDataContext db)
{
    var orders = db.Orders.Where(o => o.OrderNumber == orderNumber &&
        o.Group.GroupTypeId != (int)GroupTypeId.INTERNAL &&
        !o.Deleted);


    if (productAreaId != null)
    {
        var orders2 = orders.Where(o => o.ProductAreaId == productAreaId);
return orders2.Select(x => new {x, Type = 2 }).Concat(orders.Select(x => new {x, Type = 1 })).OrderBy(x => x.Type);
    }
    return orders;
}
```

This will return both results concatenated. First the results from orders2 then from orders2. This might help you.

If you really only want orders from one group you can do

```
GetOrders().Where(x => x.Type == GetOrders().Max(x => x.Type))
```

in order to restrict the query to the highest-priority orders. This will have suboptimal performance.

Comment: I'm trying to move away from this approach. The function needs to return an Expression<Func<Order,bool>> so it can be composable into a larger query. Maybe I should just post the larger query to make the question more clear.